# Canon Pixma TR7620 on Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at 'rendering completed'

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, canon

I recently migrated to Ubuntu 20.04 and my Canon Pixma TR7620 printer has stopped working (previous distro was Debian 11; too much for me, but at least the printer worked).

With Focal Fossa, I have already completed the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
```

AND

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt-get update
```

AND

```
sudo apt install scangearmp2 cnijfilter2
sudo apt-get update
```

AND

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sane-project/sane-release
sudo apt-get update
```

Installing all these drivers and updating everything helped Focal Fossa to recognize the printer, but right now, the printer is stuck at "Processing - Rendering completed". Nothing is printed and a few minutes later, the job disappears from the print queue.

I have tried wireless and with a USB cable. I have removed and re-installed the printer several times. I'm at a loss for what else to try.

Any suggestions will be gratefully received, because I don't have the cash to buy a new printer.

Comment: Where did you get instructions to add these PPAs?  Adding a PPA and running `apt-get update` does not do anything!  The `update` command in `apt-get` only updates the *list* of available software. It doesn't actually install anything. Also, adding multiple PPAs with the same or similar purpose can actually make things worse and mess up dependencies on your system. Please edit your question and include more details, like the guide(s) you are following. It seems you are not following them completely. I would also recommend removing the PPAs until we find the (singular) appropriate one if needed

Comment: In your third example, just to point out that the `update` command in `apt-get` always goes before any other `apt-get` commands, except for when adding new sources.  Adding sources changes the list of available software and you need an accurate current list *before* you start installing things.

Comment: On top of that, the -ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk- isn't updated since 2013. It doesn't work for 20.04, obviously. Remove it ASAP.

Comment: @Nmath,      All right, I have now removed the following:  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz, and sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sane-project/sane-release.  In terms of instructions, I have been doing my best by reading the questions and comments in Ask Ubuntu. Obviously not good enough!  Suggestions to proceed?

Comment: @ChanganAuto  Okay, thank you for that. I've removed all the PPAs now. Suggestions to proceed?

Comment: Whenever you find instructions that include PPAs always google search them. The first or among the first results you'll find the page (e.g. https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk). By the dates you should already understand but to confirm expand "techical detauls..." and then expand the "choose your..." dropdown.

Comment: The Canon Pixma TR7620 just work as is, like it did in Debian.

Comment: If not download and install Linux 64-bit drivers in .deb format directly from Canon. Even if you don't find this model (apparently not available worldwide, not mentioned in USA or EU), the drivers for any other TR series should work). I know that for recent releases it's no longer needed.

Comment: You should edit your question with the links you are following if you want us to evaluate them. With hardware that doesn't work plug & play, I always suggest going to the manufacturer for documentation and support. When I search this printer on Canon's support site and look under "drivers and downloads" and choose Linux 64-bit, I see there are several drivers published by Canon. One of which is written for debian based systems like Ubuntu.  You should be able to simply decompress this archive and run the .deb file : https://canoncanada.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1034559

Comment: You can search/review all manufacturer drivers by entering the model number at the following link: https://canoncanada.custhelp.com/app -- that being said, it's possible that some of your prior actions may have spawned a situation where this no longer works. If this option does not work on your installed system, try to implement it on a live session (Try Ubuntu from installation media). If it works on live and not on your installation, you may find it prudent to reinstall your system to set up the driver correctly

Comment: @ChanganAuto  You are absolutely correct: now my printer works 'as is', just like it did in Debian.  I have no idea why it didn't work on Friday or Saturday, because I did nothing extraordinary. It was its failure to work which led me to all the PPAs.  Either way - thank you!

Comment: @Nmath - Thank you for your help and if I run into further problems, I'll go to Canon's support site.